# How to use CloudBees Docker Custom Build Environment Plugin?

Tags: maven, jenkins, docker, jenkins-plugins, cloudbees

I try to find some documentation but I cannot find it.

I just need to build my maven project inside container. It giving lot of permission errors.

I added a maven image in the "Pull docker image from repository". then I configure the git url. When I try to build it shows this error.

```
First time build. Skipping changelog.
Pull Docker image maven from repository ...
$ docker pull maven
Failed to pull Docker image maven
FATAL: Failed to pull Docker image maven
java.io.IOException: Failed to pull Docker image maven
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.docker_build_env.PullDockerImageSelector.prepareDockerImage(PullDockerImageSelector.java:34)
    at com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.docker_build_env.DockerBuildWrapper.setUp(DockerBuildWrapper.java:167)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:156)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1738)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: have you confirmed that you can run 'docker pull maven' on the command line?    Documentation for the plugin is here:   https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-build-publish-plugin/blob/master/README.md